# How should I organise my test-pack to allow me to share an stb-tester ONE between multiple projects?

Tags: automated-testing, python, git, stb-tester

I'm using the [stb-tester ONE](https://stb-tester.com/stb-tester-one) to test my set-top box.  The Python test-cases are stored in a git repo on the device.  I'm about to start a new project and I'm wondering how I can segregate the test scripts and configuration.  I can't find a way to have multiple root folders in my test-pack.

<sup>Disclaimer: I work on stb-tester and am an employee of stb-tester.com Ltd.  This is a sanitised version of a question we've previously received through other support channels published here in an effort to seed a stb-tester support community on stackexchange.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got different test projects you could use different git repos for each, and then push them to the stb-tester ONE depending on which one you're going to be working on.  This is straight forward, but limits you to using the device on one project at a time.

One approach is use git's branching model to allow the stb-tester ONE to hold multiple projects.  With this you still have a git repo for each project locally, but you push each of them as branches to the stb-tester ONE.

**Example**

Imagine you are testing your roku product and your PS4 product.  You have two git repos locally: `roku-tests` and `ps4-tests`.  Your master branch in the local `roku-tests` repository will become roku/master on the stb-tester ONE.  You will then be able to select between them using the branch selector.

You can set up pushing to the stb-tester one like this:

```
$ cd roku-tests
$ git remote add stbt-6789 http://stb-tester-one-abc123456789.local/git/test-pack.git
$ git config remotes.device.fetch '+refs/heads/roku/*:refs/remotes/stbt-6789/*'
$ git config remotes.device.push '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/roku/*'
$ cd ../ps4-tests
$ git remote add stbt-6789 http://stb-tester-one-abc123456789.local/git/test-pack.git
$ git config remotes.device.fetch '+refs/heads/ps4/*:refs/remotes/stbt-6789/*'
$ git config remotes.device.push '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/ps4/*'
```

Now when you do `git push stbt-6789 master` in `roku-tests` you'll get a branch on the stb-tester ONE called `roku/master`.  Equally if you do `git push stbt-6789 master` in the `ps4-tests` repository you'll get a branch on the stb-tester ONE called `ps4/master`.

It'll look like:

[image: stb-tester ONE Branch selector]

Disclaimer: I work on stb-tester and am an employee of stb-tester.com Ltd.

Comment: Will, could you please add that disclaimer to your questions as well? That will prevent your questions being flagged as spam.